# Replacing one colour with another in an NSImage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage

I have an `NSImage` and want to replace one color in it with another (e.g. replace all the blue with a green colour)  Is there an easy way to do this and if not, how could I get this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for core image.  Or, you can use use Quartz Composer to figure out your image filter, and  embed a QCView in your app.

Comment: You wouldn't, because a CIImage is just an image. You need to use a filter for this. See the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/ http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/

Comment: is there a specific filter i should use or would i have to create one?